# Crystal Lang and Database Connection Pool

Tags: database, connection-pooling, crystal-lang

I have a simple code, using Kemal Crystal Framework with a database pooled connection but only mantain connection on startup, and each request decrease by one of connection to mysql.

As a **DB::Database.using_connection** says on docs:

> yields a connection from the pool the connection is returned to the
>   pool when the block ends

**Must not be closed !!!**

https://gist.github.com/valenciaj/534b5c820462db808eac13ba6c392614

Answer (score 2):

You must set **max_idle_pool_size** DB::Database parameter to mantain opened connections.